# autopep8 with vim

Tags: python, vim, pep8

Is there a way to automatically apply [autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8) to a file being edited in vim? I have the following [vimrc](https://github.com/mictadlo/vimrc4GO/blob/master/.vimrc).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to install autopep8? Apply python rules to a vimrc file?

Comment: I would install it with "easy_install -ZU autopep8 pep8". However I would prefer if I could press :w in Vim and autopep8 would fix all problems or maybe it would be possible to choose a problem in QuickFix window and fire autopep8 only for this problem.

Answer (score 27):

The correct way of using autopep8 is to rely on vim "formatprg" settings. So you add the line below to vimrc:

```
au FileType python setlocal formatprg=autopep8\ -
```

Now when you select lines in python and hit `gq` (the default mapping unless you remapped it). It will filter the lines through `autopep8` and writes the nicely formatted version in place.

The setting above also make it work with vim objects and vim motions, so you could rerender a paragraph (well lines of python code with no blank line between) using `gqap`.

To do the whole file you could do `gggqG`

The hyphen '-' at the end of the command is required to make autopep8 read the lines from the standard in.

Comment: +1: I'd consider this as the vim way. Thanks for pointing this out. I am not in favour of automagically applying autope8 to files on write. If you press ZZ, you don't see what's going on. You could add a git-pre-commit hook which runs pep8 on your sourcefiles and abort the commit if style violations
    have been detected. [see here for use of uncrustify](https://github.com/githubbrowser/Pre-commit-hooks)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you can't use the standard formatprg for things like automatically splitting long comment strings across lines.  Is there a way to still access this functionality?

Comment: I actually just discovered that I can still use the builtin using the gw command

Answer (score 8):

autopep8 is included into [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode).

Call :PymodeLintAuto or map it:

```
" Automatically fix PEP8 errors in the current buffer:
noremap <F8> :PymodeLintAuto<CR>
```

Comment: Can I map it to be run with `gqq` too? I saw `formatprg` with an external command like `autopep8` but unsure how it would work with `:PymodeLintAuto`

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do something like this to run the current file through autopep8:

```
:!autopep8 -i expand("%")
```

If you want to do this automatically on write for every python file, you can add this to your `vimrc`:

```
if has("autocmd")
    autocmd BufWritePost *.py !autopep8 -i expand("%")
endif
```

Comment: "test.py" 12L, 106C written; :!autopep8 -i expand("test.py") and than I got E855 Autocommands caused command to abort. Why?

Answer (score 3):

The plugin didn't exist yet when the question has been submitted, but now there is vim-autopep8.

https://github.com/tell-k/vim-autopep8