# Is there a Python IDE that Automatically Adds Whitespace Around Operators?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and looking for an IDE that auto formats my code and adds whitespace around operators. So x=2+2 becomes x = 2 + 2 once I've hit return. I used to work with IDE's in other languages that would tidy code like this. Does any  python IDE do this?

```
myvariable=2
# I want it to auto format to myvariable = 2 upon hitting return
```

Comment: Not sure about IDE but [autopep8](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/) would do it!

Comment: You might have some luck with eclipse pydev.

Comment: vscode has plugins that will do this.

Comment: [`vim`+`autopep8`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15285032/364696) would be one option. It would probably help if you narrowed it down to add-ons for a specific IDE you like for other reasons; this is hardly a feature worth making the deciding factor in IDE selection.

Comment: While you might have trouble getting an editor to do it as you type, any decent IDE should have a built in formatter that will fix it for you in one click afterwards.

Comment: Also, if you were so inclined, most decent IDEs would probably allow you to write your own pluggin. I doubt it's worth the effort, but that's just my opinion.